# Using array.length versus the number of elements in the array when the length is supposed to be known

Tags: java, arrays

I am studying for my exam and going through old tests.

One of the classes contained two arrays which were each supposed to have twenty elements in each.

When iterating through the arrays, is it better to use `array.length` or is it better to use the amount of elements in the array.

For example, we are going through an array and want to find the biggest classroom. I write a for loop and when writing it, is it better to use `array.length` or twenty? Code below:

```
public Clsrm biggestClsrm() {
    Clsrm classroom = new Clsrm(0, 0 , true);

    for (int i = 0; i < _clsrms.length; i++) {// or should it be for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
        if (_clsrms[i].isBigger(classroom)) {
            classroom = new Clsrm(_clsrms[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it ever safe to assume that conditions are as they should be?

Comment: Code duplication is never a good idea. Hardcoding 20 is duplicating the size of the array.

Comment: You should never assume. Don't simply assume there are 20 elements in the array. Since this is a test, validation might be something you will be graded for. Play it safe.

Comment: @Arc676 the test question says there are twenty objects, that is why I assume that there are twenty in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_clsrms.length`. Consider this *bad* code as an illustration:

```
class BadLoop {
    Clsrm _clsrms = new Clsrm[20];
    public Clsrm biggestClsrm() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The number `20` is repeated twice in the code - once in the `_clsrms` declaration, and once more in the loop.

If someone changes `20` in the declaration to `30`, then `biggestClsrm()` would ignore the last `10` classrooms when determining the biggest one. If, on the other hand, the declaration changes from `20` to `10`, then `biggestClsrm()` would stop working, because it would crash. Note that using `length` instead of a fixed number would avoid both these problems.

Essentially, the repeated part of the code becomes maintenance liability, which is easy to avoid by using `length`.